# Show the tooltip when mouse over at the object unity3d

Tags: c#, unity

i wanted to show the tooltip like this when the mouse over at the object, here is the example image:

[image]

and

[image]

i already tried this below code, but the message on the debug.log didn't showed up when i am hovering my mouse to the object, the object i give the name same like this:

```
void Update() 
{

    Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

    RaycastHit hit;

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray,out hit) && hit.collider.gameObject.name == "Yify")
    {

        Debug.Log("Yify");

    }

}
```

And here is my object (i use List to multiple the objects and each object i gave the name), (The object's name "Yify" is on the right side, dark green color):

[image]

Please help. Thank you!

Update:

i already got the script that hold movement and attack logic like the image that shown below sir @Korchkidu:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can add colliders to your objects. Then, each time the mouse "enters" the collider, it calls `void OnMouseEnter()`. When the mouse exits, it calls `void OnMouseExit()`. So just create a script like:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class TestHover : MonoBehaviour 
{
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {

    }

    void OnMouseEnter()
    {
        Debug.Log("Entering");
    }

    void OnMouseExit()
    {
        Debug.Log("Exiting");
    }
}
```

Finally, drag and drop this script onto your objects and it should work.

Comment: how do i add the script to the collider sir? i already create a sphere, and that sphere got sphere collider.. How do i attach another script to that collider? because the object that i create (sphere), already got 1 script that hold movement and attack logic in there. i already updated the question regarding the collider, please refer to it sir. thanks

Comment: drag and drop the script onto your asset.